# python config file with variable and datatypes

Tags: python, json, config

I want to provide a variable names and their datatypes in a json config file and system will be using them for further processing like

myconfig.json

```
{
   header:{
        field1:int,
        field2:long,
        field3:float,
        field4:string
    }
}
```

When a data is read from input files/sources then another program will read this configuration and will map input records with this header and datatypes and if required transformations will also be done.

example,

If I have input file like,

```
3,10,3.5,abc
3,010,3,bcd
```

I would like to parse this file with above header schema and validate and transform datatypes for these fields. this output will be json and will be fed to another system. `010` in second row should be transformed to `10` ( as it fails with json.loads) and `3` should be converted to float `3.0` etc.

I have tried using ini and conf files but failed to achieve above. Can anyone help me to achieve above behavior ?

Comment: Would `a` mean 3 should have the type of `field1`. Is there more than one header in the json file? Also are you using python3? If so python does not have long especially  anymore all ints are long

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
import re
import json
f=open('f.csv','r')


alllines=f.readlines()
a={}
for line in alllines:
    b={}
    temp=re.sub(' +',' ',line) #delete extra space in one line
    temp=temp.strip().split(',') #split using space
    b.update({'field1':int(temp[0])})
    b.update({'field2':int(temp[1])})
    b.update({'field3':float(temp[2])})
    b.update({'field4':str(temp[3])})
    a.update({'header'+str(alllines.index(line)):b})


outfile=open('x.json','w')
json.dump(a,outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using pandas, json and (numpy):

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np

# Create a file (csv) for test purposes 
data = '''\
3,10,3.5,abc
3,010,3,bcd'''
file = io.StringIO(data)

# Create a file (json) for test purposes
json_data = '''\
{
   "header":[
       ["field1","int16"],
       ["field2","float32"],
       ["field3","float64"],
       ["field4","str"]]
}'''

# Load json to dictionary
json_d = json.loads(json_data)

# Fetch field names and dtypes
names = [i[0] for i in json_d['header']]
dtype = dict(json_d['header'])

# Now use pandas to read the whole thing to a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(file,header=None,names=names,dtype=dtype)

# Output as dict (this can be passed to a json file with json.dump())
df.to_dict('r')
```

Result:

```
[{'field1': 3, 'field2': 10.0, 'field3': 3.5, 'field4': 'abc'},
 {'field1': 3, 'field2': 10.0, 'field3': 3.0, 'field4': 'bcd'}]
```